# automated push to a github repo with travis

Tags: git, github, automation, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have a gitub.io repo which hosts my webpage -- the source for that webpage (uncompiled Jade / Sass code) is in a separate public repo. [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/wbar8417/w.barlow) is set up to watch my source repo for changes and run the compile suite, generating the HTML/CSS that will get pushed to the github.io repo.

Can I set up Travis to automatically do a push to a github repo I own if the compile passed, without hard-coding my username and password into my `.travis.yml` file (obviously this is a security concern)?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659713/can-commits-pushes-to-github-be-automated), but it wasn't answered with Travis in mind -- I don't think I can use keypair authentication because I'd need to put the private key in the repo or in the travis script, which is just as big a security hole as putting in my password.

---

For anyone else who winds up here, I found the following information using roidrage's answer as a springboard:

1. Travis uses public/private key encryption to allow you to embed sensitive information in a `.travis.yml` file. You can install their gem called "travis" and use it to encrypt stuff, and they'll decrypt it securely on their end. Documentation: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/
2. On github, you can generate a "personal access token" in your [applications settings](https://github.com/settings/applications). This can be used like a password by applications. Encrypt that using the above technique and throw it in your yaml.

Comment: Travis asks for a variable (`SOMEVAR`). Which variable should I use?

Comment: in my case, i encrypted an ssh private key (the deploy key) using the travis gem. i stored the encrypted private key in the repo. travis downloads the repo, decrypts the private key, and then pushes back to the repo using the decrypted key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by storing a token to access GitHub in an encrypted way in the .travis.yml file. See our [docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) for examples on how to encrypt data.

As for the push to GitHub Pages, there's a [blog post](http://kevinyap.ca/2014/06/deploying-pelican-sites-using-travis-ci/) summing up the steps quite well, and it even points to [a script](https://github.com/iKevinY/iKevinY.github.io/blob/src/generate.sh) that you can use in your build.

A mirror of the script is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script was written to facilitate the deployment process of Pelican
# websites using Travis CI. See this blog post for more information:
# http://kevinyap.ca/2014/06/deploying-pelican-sites-using-travis-ci/

usage="Usage: $(basename "$0") (deploy | diff | serve)

Commands:
  deploy     Upload site to Github Pages
  diff       Compare locally generated site to live site
  serve      Generate and serve site (auto-reloads on changes)"

TARGET_REPO="iKevinY/iKevinY.github.io"
GH_PAGES_BRANCH="master"

DEVELOP_CONF="pelicanconf.py"
PUBLISH_CONF="publishconf.py"

OUTPUT_DIR="output"
REMOTE_DIR="remote"

PY_CMD="python3"
SERVER="http.server"
PORT="8000"

rootPath="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"

generate_site() {
  # Based on http://zonca.github.io/2013/09/automatically-build-pelican-and-publish-to-github-pages.html
  if [ "$TRAVIS" == "true" ]; then
    # Ensure that builds triggered by pull requests are not deployed
    if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" != "false" ]; then
      echo "Successfully built pull request #$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST."
      exit 0
    fi

    echo "Deploying site to $GH_PAGES_BRANCH branch of $TARGET_REPO."
    git config --global user.email "travis@travis-ci.org"
    git config --global user.name "Travis CI"
  else
    cd "$rootPath" || exit 1
    pelican -s $PUBLISH_CONF
  fi

  # Pull hash and commit message of the most recent commit
  commitHash=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
  commitMessage=$(git log -1 --pretty=%B)

  # Clone the GitHub Pages branch and rsync it with the newly generated files
  GITHUB_REPO=https://${GH_TOKEN:-git}@github.com/${TARGET_REPO}.git
  git clone --branch $GH_PAGES_BRANCH --depth 1 "$GITHUB_REPO" $REMOTE_DIR &> /dev/null
  rsync -r --exclude=.git --delete $OUTPUT_DIR/ $REMOTE_DIR/
  pushd $REMOTE_DIR > /dev/null

  git add -A
  git status -s

  $1  # execute the function that was passed as an argument
}

push_changes() {
  if [ "$TRAVIS" == "true" ]; then
    longMessage="Generated by $commitHash; pushed by build #$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER."
    git commit -m "$commitMessage" -m "$longMessage"
    git push origin $GH_PAGES_BRANCH &> /dev/null || echo "Push failed."
  else
    read -rp "Push changes to GitHub Pages? [y/N] " response
    if [[ "$response" =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
      git commit -m "$commitMessage" -m "Generated by $commitHash."
      git push origin $GH_PAGES_BRANCH
    fi

    popd > /dev/null
    rm -rf -- $REMOTE_DIR $OUTPUT_DIR && echo "Removed $REMOTE_DIR and $OUTPUT_DIR."
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  'deploy')
    generate_site push_changes
    ;;

  'diff')
    generate_site 'git --no-pager diff --cached --color-words'
    ;;

  'serve')
    developPath=${rootPath}/develop
    local_ip=$(ifconfig | grep 'inet ' | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}')

    # Seed directory with site content
    cd "$rootPath" && pelican -s $DEVELOP_CONF > /dev/null
    echo "Serving HTTP at $(tput bold)${local_ip}:${PORT}$(tput sgr0)."

    cleanup() {
      pkill -f $SERVER
      cd "$rootPath" && rm -r "$developPath" && echo && exit 0
    }

    trap cleanup SIGINT

    (pelican -rs $DEVELOP_CONF 2> /dev/null) &
    (cd "$developPath" || exit 1; $PY_CMD -m $SERVER $PORT 1> /dev/null) &
    wait
    ;;

  *)
    echo "$usage"
    exit 2
    ;;

esac
```

Answer (score 0):

> Mac OS El Capitan requires Ruby ^2.2

```
brew unlink ruby; brew install Ruby
gem install travis
```

> Use the travis gem to encrypt your secret PAT and update your `.travis.yml`

```
travis encrypt  GH_TOKEN=<secret github personal access token> --add
```