# Github: Reject commits containing DOS newline characters

Tags: git, github, newline, dos

Is there a way for github to completely reject a commit if DOS newline characters are in any of the files?

(I know the github interface has a setting to make sure the DOS newline characters are not committed, but in the case that this setting isn't turned on, I'd like some insurance.)

Comment: This could also be extended to reject any commits containing tab characters in lieu of spaces also.

Comment: *Is there a way for github to completely reject a commit [...]* Do you mean at commit time, or at push time? In the first case, a `pre-commit` [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) is probably what you need.

Comment: a hook able to deny a GitHub push? Not sure: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31334040/6309

Comment: @Jubobs: Either would work honestly. But I was thinking of push time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way for github to completely reject a commit

That sounds like a server-side hook. That isn't possible: a GitHub webhook can register a push event, not reject a push.

That leaves you with a **[client side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#Client-Side-Hooks)** (which needs to be deployed on *all* client, and can be bypassed anyway)

A pre-commit hook is more sensible in that case (no need to wait for the push to discover a commit with a wrong content).

You also have then option of `.gitattributes` (see "[Mind the End of Your Line](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)") in order to instruct git to always replace CRLF by LF (`*.txt eol=lf`): see [`.gitattributes` End-of-line conversion](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_end_of_line_conversion).
That is more robust than a client-side hook.